# React - Strict Mode off, functional component constructed second time after first state change only

Tags: reactjs

I'm confused why function components (non class components don't confuse with functional) are constructed twice when state changes?

My understanding was that the function is constructed once just like a class' component constructor?

**Note:** React is NOT running in strict mode.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-roentgen-9cyg1?file=/src/App.js)

Sample code:

**index.js:**

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, // notice no strict mode
  rootElement
);
```

**Eg 1:** LogStatement called once - simple and obvious:

```
function App1() {
  console.log("App constructed");
  return <div>Hello</div>;
}
```

**Eg 2:** LogStatement called twice - not quite obvious but maybe its due to setDidMount ? :

```
function App2() {
  console.log("App constructed");
  const [didMount, setDidMount] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setDidMount(true);
  }, []);

  return <div>Hello</div>;
}
```

**Eg 3:** LogStatement called twice. no matter how many independent state variables:

```
function App3() {
  console.log("App constructed:" + i++);

  const [didMount, setDidMount] = useState(false);
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState("empty");

  useEffect(() => {
    setDidMount(true);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSomeState("full");
  }, []);

  return <div>Hello</div>;
}
```

Finally class component

**Eg 4:** LogStatement called once - as expected

```
class App4 extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      didMount: false
    };
    console.log("App constructed:" + i++);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      didMount: true
    });
  }

  render() {
     return <div>Hello</div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding was that the function is constructed once just like a class' component constructor?

It's not constructed at all, that's just a class thing. Putting a log statement in the body of a function component is roughly equivalent to putting it in the `render` method of a class component. So your log is telling you how many times the component rendered. Setting state causes rendering (usually), so by calling `setDidMount(true)`, you are rerendering the component.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Leading question: Where yould you instantiate something like `const api = new Api(window.location);` in the case where: 1. Its SSR and window is not available 2.window.location cannot be read from process.env as it can be multiple subdomains aka: domain.com and dashboard.domain.com 3. You want this instance as singleton, so no prop change affects it, except window.location change? Note: When doing SSR window.location is available in methods like componentDidMount or useEffect().

Comment: I have no experience with SSR. You should ask this as a new question.

Comment: Will do thanks :). So in a non SSR scenario instantiating anything outside the function equals like instantiating things in a class component's constructor?